React Web FF DevTools Profile Flamegraph "Why did this render?" has "The parent component rendered", but Flamegraph does not show activated parent?
I am developing React web SPA ERP application with dynamic mulitabbed interface and I am having problems with extra-rerenderings. I am thinking about different options (e.g. my question about component design https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/455372/singe-page-application-for-the-web-with-dynamic-tabbed-interface-is-there-ne/455375) and I am doing profiling of my code and I have arrived at this situation: 
My application is: the user can open new in-app tabs, each new form is opened as respective component-view in its own tab. I tested my application: I opened my application with the default Dashboard tab visible then I clicked on the link and opened other view in its onw in-application tab and then I switched back to the Dashboard tab and back to the new tab. TabPanel (key=0) is the TabPanel component that hosts Dashboard component.
So - clicking on the link, swithcing between tabs - all this is causing url changes (for the same domain, of course, this if SPA app after all) and url changes are processed in a manner that causes changes to the data (tabs array and activeTabId variable) and data ar rendered into Tab's and TabPanel's.
Of course - each url change and activeTabId may cause and causes re-renders, including re-render of TabPanel key=0, that is OK. But the strange situation is, that after each re-render due to url (react-router-dom location) change and re-render after activeTabId change, there are 4 re-renders of TabPanel key=0 due to "Why did this render?"="The parent component rendered" - see picture. And the Flamegraphs shows no re-rendered parent for any of those 4 re-rerenders! This is really strange. How the component may be re-rendered due to parent re-render, if there is no re-rendered parent. I have checked the parent re-renders and they count was minimal. Can ir be possible that for one parent re-render (e.g. due to url/location change or activeTabId change) there can be following 4 extra re-renders of the children to the parent?
I am giving the full code of the minimal app (I summarized it from my production app but I have not tested this summarized app, it illustrates my approach: 1) any view open or switching between tabs goes through url changes, 2) that are handled by the router, saved into data and 3) Tab's/TabPanel's are rendered from those data dynamically) at the end, but here is the crux of rendering of TapPabel's - maybe this rendering is somehow inefficient and introduces parent problems?
  {tabs.map((tab) => (
    <TabPanel key={tab.id} tab_hidden={activeTabId !== tab.id}>
      {tab.component}
    </TabPanel>
  ))}

Here is one-pager with full (summarized, essential code):
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Tabs, Tab, Box } from '@mui/material';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

// Closable Tab component
const ClosableTab = React.memo(({ label, onClose, closable }) => (
  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <span>{label}</span>
    {closable && (
      <CloseIcon
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          onClose();
        }}
        sx={{ ml: 1, cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: 'small' }}
      />
    )}
  </Box>
));

// TabPanel component
const TabPanel = React.memo(({ children, tab_hidden }) => (
  <div role="tabpanel" hidden={tab_hidden} style={{ display: tab_hidden ? 'none' : 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1 }}>
    <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>{children}</Box>
  </div>
));

// Create a new tab
const createTab = (id, path, label, component, closable = true) => ({
  id,
  path,
  label,
  component,
  closable,
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MainApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

// MainApp Component with Tab and Routing Logic
const MainApp = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([
    createTab(0, '/dashboard', 'Dashboard', <DashboardView />, false),
  ]);
  const [activeTabId, setActiveTabId] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentPath = location.pathname;
    const foundTab = tabs.find((tab) => tab.path === currentPath);
    if (foundTab) {
      setActiveTabId(foundTab.id);
    }
  }, [location.pathname, tabs]);

  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    const selectedTab = tabs.find((tab) => tab.id === newValue);
    if (selectedTab) {
      navigate(selectedTab.path);
    }
    setActiveTabId(newValue);
  };

  const addTab = (path, label, component) => {
    const newId = tabs.length;
    const newTab = createTab(newId, path, label, component);
    setTabs((prev) => [...prev, newTab]);
    setActiveTabId(newTab.id);
    navigate(path);
  };

  const closeTab = (tabId) => {
    setTabs((prev) => prev.filter((tab) => tab.id !== tabId));
    setActiveTabId((prev) => (prev === tabId ? 0 : prev)); // Switch to Dashboard if closing active
    navigate('/dashboard');
  };

  const memoizedTabs = useMemo(
    () =>
      tabs.map((tab) => (
        <Tab
          key={tab.id}
          value={tab.id}
          label={<ClosableTab label={tab.label} onClose={() => closeTab(tab.id)} closable={tab.closable} />}
        />
      )),
    [tabs]
  );

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      <Tabs value={activeTabId} onChange={handleTabChange} variant="scrollable" scrollButtons="auto">
        {memoizedTabs}
      </Tabs>

      {tabs.map((tab) => (
        <TabPanel key={tab.id} tab_hidden={activeTabId !== tab.id}>
          {tab.component}
        </TabPanel>
      ))}

      <Box sx={{ p: 2 }}>
        <button onClick={() => addTab('/tab1', 'Tab 1', <ExampleView id={1} />)}>Open Tab 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => addTab('/tab2', 'Tab 2', <ExampleView id={2} />)}>Open Tab 2</button>
      </Box>

      {/* Routes for different views */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardView />} />
        <Route path="/tab1" element={<ExampleView id={1} />} />
        <Route path="/tab2" element={<ExampleView id={2} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
};

// Example views
const DashboardView = React.memo(() => (
  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <p>This is the dashboard view.</p>
  </div>
));

const ExampleView = React.memo(({ id }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Tab {id}</h2>
    <p>This is content for tab {id}.</p>
  </div>
));

export default App;

